# "If you don't kill me, the precogs were wrong and Precrime is over" -- How?

Tags: minority-report

In Minority Report (2002), at around 2:13:45, Burgess approaches Anderton and Anderton says:

> No doubt the Precogs have already seen this. You see the dilemma, don't you? **If you don't kill me, Precogs were wrong and Precrime is over**. If you do kill me, you go away. But it proves the system works. The Precogs were right.

My question is about the bold-faced statement. Isn't the exact point of Precrime is so that the murder **doesn't** happen? And how would the Precogs be wrong if Burgess does kill him? The Precogs predict that a murder on Anderton will occur, perpetrated by Burgess, and so if it does happen, then the Precogs are correct (not wrong, according to the statement).

Comment: "How would the Precogs be wrong if Burgess does kill him?" - They wouldn't be. Hence the second part of the statement: "**If you do kill me**, you go away. But it proves the system works. **The Precogs were right.**"

Comment: Your question as it is written is very confusing. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't the exact point of Precrime so that the murder doesn't happen?

Precrime assumes that people will do what the Precogs see, unless *someone else* intervenes. So the Precogs see a future murder, and Precrime sends officers to stop the murderer from killing the victim. So the exact point of Precrime *is* to stop murder, as you said, but it assumes that murderers won't / can't stop themselves. Law enforcement has to stop them.

> And how would the Precogs be wrong if Burgess does kill him?

The Precogs would not be wrong. They would be right.  That's what the quote says: "If you do kill me, you go away. But it proves the system works. The Precogs were right." The phrase "you go away" is a slang term referring to Burgess being imprisoned (via one of those headbands they put on criminals to control / stop their minds).

Answer (score 0):

I think it refers to the intention of killing him. If Burgess does not have any intention of really killing him that means that the crime would never occur and the Precrime should never have seen it, but instead the Precogs see that the crime is going to happen so that Burgess must have a real intention of killing him. Of course, Precogs should act before the crime is committed.

In short I think that Burgess is really going to kill him but as he says ([from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_Report_(film)#Plot)):

> Once people are aware of their future, they are able to change it.

so after seeing the future his intention to kill Anderton disappears.

Burgess had the intention of killing Anderton so the crime was going to happen until he saw his own future.